# Beginner question: uv unwrap unexpected unwrapped shape

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

So I unwrapped a wrench model and marked the seam:
[image]

The unwrapped part of the u-shaped faces are like this:
[image]

Any idea why I end up having the diagonal lines (the red line) there? There are no doubles, and I think there's no extra face/edge/point around because I couldn't select face or edge on those diagonal lines.

Comment: Or...is it a mesh too high-poly to conduct operations like unwrapping and sculpting?

Comment: the root cause of this problem is the same as the other question you posted before, big non-convex n-gons. You need to at least split the face of the spanner into only convex parts.

Comment: Agreed, you need to make all of your faces convex (all interior angles for a face are less than 180 degrees), where each face has at most 4 sides.

Comment: I see. Really got to remember this non-convex n-gon thing then. Thank you very much!!!